# The geometry of a commutative ring and the topology of its ideal complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $\mathcal{P}(R)$ be the poset of ideals of $R$ ordered by inclusion, and let $\Delta(R)$ be the order complex of $\mathcal{P}(R)$. $\Delta(R)$ is a simplicial complex naturally associated with R.

What does the topology of $\Delta(R)$ tell us about the geometry of $Spec (R)$?

We can ask the question more generally about the order complex $\Delta(X)$ of the poset of closed subschemes associated with a Noetherian scheme.

Primary question is: if for two schemes $X$ and $X'$, $\Delta(X')$ is homeomorphic (resp. homotopic) to $\Delta(X)$, what is the corresponding relationship between $X$ and $X'$?

Comment: "What does the topology of $\Delta (R)$  tell us about the geometry of $\operatorname{Spec}(R) $?" Not much: $\Delta(R)$ is the same for all discrete valuation rings $R$.

Comment: Extending the comment of @abx: more generally any local ring $R$ (=unique maximal ideal) will have its maximal ideal as a cone point of $\Delta(R)$, hence $\Delta(R)$ will be contractible.